# how can we split column names on base of Delimiter from configuration file( having column names )

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have text file with column names as below in Columns.txt

```
Employee_ID|X
Employee_Name|X
Age|Y
```

I am reading above columns as per below method..

```
with open("Columns.txt") as c:
    columns_list = c.readlines()
columns_list=[col.replace('\n','') for col in columns_list]
print(columns_list)

Output :  ['Employee_ID|X', 'Employee_Name|X', 'Age|Y']
```

how can i restrict the columns in the output having 2nd "|" pipe delimiter value   having "X".

```
Example:  Output : should be like [Employee_ID,Employee_Name]
```

Please help with any suggestion or syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use:

```
    with open("Columns.txt") as c:
        columns_list = c.readlines()
    columns_list=[col[:col.replace('\n','').find('|')] for col in columns_list]
```

edit after correction:

```
columns_list=[col[:col.replace('\n','').find('|X')] for col in columns_list if col.find('|X') >0 ]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. But i wan to pick the columns only wherever 2nd value of "|" delimiter having "X" 

    Output : should be like [Employee_ID,Employee_Name]

Comment: I have edited the loop so that it saves only the col where '|X' is present

Answer (score 3):

You can just use:

```
with open("Columns.txt") as c:
    columns_list = [col for line in c for col, x in [line.strip().split('|')]
                    if x == 'X']

print(columns_list)
```

It should display:

```
['Employee_ID', 'Employee_Name']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot serge. But I have a filter , wherever 2nd value having "X"  - "|" delimeter i want to consider only those values.

Comment: @ Output : should be display only  ['Employee_ID','Employee_Name']

Comment: @Arya: My bad. I had missed an important point with the filter part. Post edited.

Comment: I am getting ValueError: I/O operation on closed file. is there anything i need to add

Comment: @Arya Is there any indentation problem in your code? It runs with no errors on my system.

Comment: @No Serge , i dont have any Indentation problem